# How do I conditionally sort on a second column using a custom MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I've got a result set I have to sort in quite a complex way. There are two fields (A and B) which are employed in the sorting, and the algorithm is like this:

1. Sort by field A
2. Then, if the field A contains a substring K, sort by field B using a custom function F (see below). If the field A doesn't contain K, the built-in sorting for B is just fine.

More information:

- The field A is a VARCHAR.
- The field B is an INTEGER that can have the following values: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.
- Function F is simple as "sort values in this way: {4, 5, 1, 2, 3}".

How can I do this in MySQL through a SQL query? Am I forced to do it cient-side?

Comment: You may be able to do the sort through a subquery, but you need to post your query string.

Comment: Just to clarify your sort... A, no problem.  then... do you want pre-sorted any entries that have the "K" variable sorted before all others that do NOT have the "K", THEN do the sort on "B", otherwise, you will just be interlacing the "B" values when there is or is not a "K" value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
…
ORDER BY
  A,
  CASE WHEN A LIKE CONCAT('%', K, '%') THEN Func(B) ELSE B END
```